# Change tableview data according to textfield in swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, uitextfield

I want to change the `TableView` data according to `Textfield`. when a user taps on `Textfield` and starts editing it will change the `TableView data` accordingly. I saw a lot of examples on but mainly I found about search bar any help would be appreciated. Please note that this is textfield not seacrhbar

Comment: You can add a target for `textFieldDidChange` and in that target method you can do your needful.

Comment: i want to know the code of table view

Comment: You´re looking for a [UISearchController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisearchcontroller).

Comment: no not search controller i am using textfield

Comment: What exactly will change when you type something in your textfield?

Comment: Explain more about what you exactly want so we can help

Comment: I am using a google place api in my project and when user enter location in textfield it will show the filtered data in tableview

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try

```
var searchActive : Bool = false

var data = ["San Francisco","New York","San Jose","Chicago","Los Angeles","Austin","Seattle"]

var filtered:[String] = []


   textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.textFieldDidChange(_:)),
                          for: UIControlEvents.editingChanged)
```

and handle method:

```
@objc func textFieldDidChange(_ textField: UITextField) {

 // filter tableViewData with textField.text

  let searchText  = textField.text

  filtered = data.filter({ (text) -> Bool in
        let tmp: NSString = text as NSString
        let range = tmp.range(of: searchText, options: NSString.CompareOptions.caseInsensitive)
        return range.location != NSNotFound
    })
    if(filtered.count == 0){
        searchActive = false;
    } else {
        searchActive = true;
    }
     self.tableView.reloadData()

}



func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


  let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:CellIdentifier1) as! generalTableViewCell

    if(searchActive){
        cell.titlelb.text = filtered[indexPath.row]
    } else {
        cell.titlelb.text = data[indexPath.row];
    }
 }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if(searchActive){
       return filtered.count
    } else {
        return data.count
    }
}
```

Comment: showing an error is that index out range at here cell.titlelb.text = filtered[indexPath.row]

Comment: Excellent answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement `textFieldDelegate` in the view controller and then in the delegate method `textFieldDidChange` you can change the tableview datasource according to your use and reload the tableview after that.